# Nested table css broken

Tags: html, css

I have a nested table but for some reason, the CSS selector seems broken after the nested table.

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="yellow">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table>
      <tr class="yellow">
        <td>
          5
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr class="yellow">
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsbin.com/zuxagenoba/edit?html,css,output

Comment: What do you mean by "broken"? http://nimb.ws/w4tKul

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid. You have a `<table>` as a child of a `<tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that your nested table (the one which contains 5) is a direct child of tr element and you have a missing td element. Wrapping that table with  and  fixes the issue.
See code snippet below

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="yellow">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table>
      <tr class="yellow">
        <td>
          5
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="yellow">
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: oh, I see the nested table needs to be inside a td then, thanks a lot!